# ControlsFX Autocomplete, how to get selected Object?

Tags: javafx-8, controlsfx

I've created TextField

```
TextField txtAutocomplete = new TextField();
```

and List of entities

```
List<Batch> list = BatchService.list();
```

and made it autocompletable using ControlsFX TextFields

```
AutoCompletionBinding<Batch> autoCompletionBinding = TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(txtAutocomplete, list);
```

is there a way to retrieve a Batch object from autoCompletionBinding when user selects one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you have a look at [`AutoCompletionBinding.setOnAutoCompleted()`](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/textfield/AutoCompletionBinding.html#setOnAutoCompleted-javafx.event.EventHandler-)?

You will get notified upon successful auto-completion with an [`AutoCompletionEvent`](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/textfield/AutoCompletionBinding.AutoCompletionEvent.html).

Comment: Thank you for reply, Yes I did looked at AutoCompletionEvent but there is only notification about auto complete.

Comment: @latsha according to the JavaDocs this is the only event you will get.